# Getting "std::bad_alloc" error when using vector in C++ to populate elements

Tags: vector, stack-overflow

I'm encountering a std::bad_alloc error in my C++ code when attempting to create a vector and populate it with elements. Below is a snippet of the code that is causing the issue:

[image]

The program terminates with the error message terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'. I'm unable to figure out why this error is occurring. Could someone please provide insight into what is causing this error and how to resolve it? Thank you!

Comment: How many elements do you expect that loop to insert? How do you think `arr.size()` relates to the number of elements you push into `arr`? How many elements do you expect to be already in `arr` _before_ you do any of the `push_back`?